# Srcollableview in swapview in dojox mobile

Tags: android, dojo, cordova, dojox.mobile

I have noticed strange thing - when I put ScrollableView into SwapView and I programmatically (after clicking on button) change view in SwamView and next give focus (click one elment in list) to list in ScrollableView, the first view appear under this one with list in ScrollableView which is currently main view (both are visible at the same time - one superimposed on the other). I use it in PhoneGap as a Android project. And the version of Dojo which I use is 1.9.

My code is:

```
<div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SwapView">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane" data-dojo-props='href:"page1.html", parseOnLoad: false, onLoad:NewClientForm.loadForm'></div>
</div>

<div id="view2" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/SwapView">
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ContentPane" id="cview2" data-dojo-props='href:"page2.html", parseOnLoad: true'></div>
</div>
```

and the page2.html

```
<div id="offer_page">
<div class="pageLogo">
    <img src="theme/images/logo.png" alt="" />
</div>

<header>
    <h1 id="offer_page_client_name_header"> </h1>
</header>

<div id="new_client_nav_menu" class="pageNavMenu">
    <div>menu</div>
</div>
<div id="new_client_nav_settings" class="pageNavSettings">
    <div>set</div>
</div>
<div class="pageNavPrev">
    <div id="offer_page_nav_prev" class="pageImageLink" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props='onClick: OfferPageForm.prevButton'><img src="theme/images/nav_prev.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="pageNavNext">
    <div id="offer_page_nav_next" class="pageImageLink" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-props="onClick: OfferPageForm.nextButton"><img src="theme/images/nav_next.png" alt=""></div>
</div>

<ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBar" data-dojo-props='barType:"standardTab", center:false'>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='selected:true, moveTo:"tab1"'>Client data</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"tab2"'>Needs analysis</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"tab3"'>Offers</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='moveTo:"tab4"'>Simulations</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" class="tabView">
    Client data:
</div>

<div id="tab2" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" class="tabView">
    Needs analysis
</div>

<div id="tab3" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" class="tabView">
    <div class="offersLeftPanel">
        <div class="offersLeftPanelTableHeader">
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableDate">Creation date</div>
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableProduct">Product</div>
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableName">Name</div>
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableRisk">Risk Profile</div>
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableStatus">Status</div>
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableSigned">Signed</div>
            <div class="offersLeftPanelTableActions">Actions</div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" data-dojo-props="height: '88%'">
            <ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList">
                <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" class="offersLeftPanelTableRow">
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableDate">2013-03-25 08:00</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableProduct">iSave Target</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableName">iSavetarget-Medium-1</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableRisk">Neutral</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableStatus">New</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableSigned">No</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableActions"></div>
                </li>
                <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" class="offersLeftPanelTableRow">
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableDate">2013-03-25 08:00</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableProduct">iSave Target</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableName">iSavetarget-Medium-1</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableRisk">Neutral</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableStatus">New</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableSigned">No</div>
                    <div class="offersLeftPanelTableActions"></div>
                </li>
                             ...
                             </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="offersRightPanel">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" class="offersOtherNeedsButton">Other uncovered needs</div>

        <div class="offersBottomButtons">
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" class="offersConsolidateButton">Consolidate offers and issue</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" class="offersIssueButton">Issue proposal</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab4" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" class="tabView">
    Simulations
</div>
```

page1.html looks very similar, but ther are no lists and ScrollableViews.

The most *interesting* thing is the fact that it occurs not every time and not on every devices on which I have a chance to test it (I tested it on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2? - here I have noticed this issue, Asus Transformer and one "no name").

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using a dojox/mobile/ScrollablePane instead.  Views are really meant to be a whole screen.

Comment: Yes, I have but it hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML in your page2.html seems malformed (the top-level  is not closed). Besides that, the HTML you posted uses JavaScript and CSS pieces which are missing. All in one, I can't correctly run your code to see if I reproduce.

On the other side, one of the SwapView tests in dojox/mobile/tests (test_SwapView.html) includes a button which programmatically transitions to a swap view - quite close to what you describe. Do you reproduce using this sample or can you modify it to reproduce your issue?

Finally, telling the Android version of the devices where you reproduce would help too.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but the problem turned out to be related to something else and today I found a solution: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17164